# WatchGuard blocking internal UDP packets

Tags: firewall, watchguard

I'm seeing lots of packets that our WatchGuard firewall is dropping.

They're all hitting either 255.255.255.255. or 224.0.0.1 using UDP 8612 / 1947 / 17500.

Since I've started seeing these messages our internet seems a lot slower. How can I allow these through?

Comment: You can't allow them through because they aren't trying to go *through*, they are trying to hit the Watchguard. So you could allow UDP port 8612 from Trusted to Firebox and they would stop showing up in the logs, but it wouldn't do anything because the firewall isn't going to answer Dropbox or Canon printer or SafeNet license discovery messages.

Answer (score 1):

This is broadcast and multicast traffic.  It sounds like your internal network is becoming more noisy then it once was. I know UDP 17500 is the Dropbox discovery protocol.

Check your network and you may need to implement multicast and broadcast limitations on your switches.

Answer (score 0):

You can't allow them *through* because they aren't trying to go through, they are trying to hit the Watchguard. So you could allow UDP port 8612 from Trusted to Firebox and they would stop showing up in the logs, but it wouldn't do anything because the firewall isn't going to answer Canon printer software discovery messages.